# How do I specify Index Values in Python? IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

Tags: python, pandas, index-error

I am able to load this excel worksheet properly but do not know how to specify that I want data from the entire first column to be read.
[Screenshot of Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHBcy.png)

```
import pandas as pd

# Load Excel sheet for CAP settings
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\FILENAMEHERE.xlsx')
print (df)

#Find settings on CAP database excel sheet using CAP ID
capacitor_row = capacitor_settings_df[capacitor_settings_df['CAP_ID'] == cap_id_input.iloc[0]
```

I added a line to print the excel workbook in order to verify that it was loading correctly and it is. I am not sure how to read the first column of the excel sheet which is titled "CAP_ID". I have tried specifying the iloc[1] but do not know how to format this in order to read only the first column.

Comment: `df['CAP_ID']` is the column you are interested in as Pandas Series. I am not sure what the `capacitor_row ...`statement is intended to do as it does not make much sense.

Comment: (1) `capacitor_settings_df` and `cap_id_input` aren't set in the shown code. What are they? (2) The code is syntactically incorrect (missing closing bracket).

Comment: `.iloc[1]` will retrieve the second row of df (the first row would be .iloc[0]), not the first column. If you want to retrieve the first column by index, use `.iloc[:, 0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `CAP_ID` is a column in the Excel file, then you can do the following;

```
import pandas as pd

# Load Excel sheet for CAP settings
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\FILENAMEHERE.xlsx')
print (df)

#Find settings on CAP database excel sheet using CAP ID
df['CAP_ID']
```

If you want to locate values from a column named `capacitor_settings` based on a known `CAP_ID`, then you can do the following.

```
import pandas as pd 

# Load Excel sheet for CAP settings
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\FILENAMEHERE.xlsx')
print (df)

# select values from a column based on values in another column
df['capacitor_settings'].where(df['CAP_ID'] == 'xyz')
```

If you want to locate values from a column named `capacitor_settings` based on several known values of `CAP_ID`, then you can do the following.

```
   # Load Excel sheet for CAP settings
    df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\FILENAMEHERE.xlsx')
    print (df)

    # select values from a column based on multipe values in another column
    df['capacitor_settings'].where(df['CAP_ID'].isin(['xyz', 'abc']))
```